# I am using a owl Carousel Plugin on my Joomla site. When I hover over the carousel, it stop the autoplay. I don't want it to stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a owl Carousel Plugin on my Joomla site. When I hover over the carousel, it stop the autoplay. I don't want it to stop. I want it to continue autoplay even on mouseover. I don't understand Javascript but pasting the Owl Carousel JS section where this is hover. Is there a way to modify this so as not to stop the autoplay on hover?

```
},this),"play.owl.autoplay":a.proxy(function(a,b,c){this.play(b,c)},this),"stop.owl.autoplay":a.proxy(function(){this.stop()},this),"mouseover.owl.autoplay":a.proxy(function(){this.core.settings.autoplayHoverPause&&this.pause()},this),"mouseleave.owl.autoplay":a.proxy(function(){this.core.settings.autoplayHoverPause&&this.autoplay()},this)},this.core.$element.on(this.handlers)};d.Defaults={autoplay:!1,autoplayTimeout:5e3,autoplayHoverPause:!1,autoplaySpeed:!1},d.prototype.autoplay=function(){this.core.settings.autoplay&&!this.core.state.videoPlay?(b.clearInterval(this.interval),this.interval=b.setInterval(a.proxy(function(){this.play()},this),this.core.settings.autoplayTimeout)):b.clearInterval(this.interval)},d.prototype.play=function(){return c.hidden===!0||this.core.state.isTouch||this.core.state.isScrolling||this.core.state.isSwiping||this.core.state.inMotion?void 0:this.core.settings.autoplay===!1
```

I apologize is if this is not the proper way to ask this question to solve this issue.

Comment: If you are doing Joomla development, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the behaviour of the owl carousel with this code. Add this to the bottom of the page on which you have the carousel.   and set 'stopOnHover' to true

```
$('your-carousel-id-or-class').owlCarousel({
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    stopOnHover:true <===
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true
})
```

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. I don't want it to pause on hover. I want it to continue play on hover. I tried your solution using "False" value but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: then set   stopOnHover: false in the code above and put it  at the bottom of the page

Comment: I tried this:
```
 $('sppb-carousel1').owlCarousel({
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    stopOnHover:false
    loop:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true
})
```
Doesn't work!

Comment: is  sppb-carousel1 the CSS class or id of your carousel? if' it's a class then you do $('.sppb-carousel1') .i.e (add a dot in front) else if it's an id then you do $('#sppb-carousel1')  i.e (add a hash in front) to select the carousel with jquery. You might also want to get help from someone who can code. I

Comment: Thank you for correcting me @Nkunim. I tried it but still doesn't work. I am stuck with this. :( Hopefully I will get a solution soon.

Comment: @MJNkunim If you are able to support Joomla questions or questions related to its extensions, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and see if you can help us to resolve some of our open questions.